# How do you calculate the probability when you don't know how many trials will be held?

Tags: probability

You toss a fair coin until you toss two consecutive heads. Find the probability that you have to toss the coins exactly 4 times.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the probability of getting one of the following sequences of $4$ tosses:  $TTHH,HTHH$.  Right? (reading from left to right, just to be clear)

Comment: Yes, exactly! I understand that there are two ways that that can happen, which you specified. But I don't know how to account for the probability that we flip the coin 4 times exactly.

Comment: If the statement ended at "exactly 4 times", it would be clearer.

Comment: That's true. I will edit it.

Comment: Is it possible to think of it as a binomial distribution with 4 trials? I don't know if that works or not.

Comment: There are exactly $16$ equally probable sequences of four tosses.  The probability that one of two preferred ones occurs is therefore $\frac 2{16}=\frac 18$.

Comment: I will point out that you asked [essentially the same question yesterday](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617259/probability-of-success-on-third-and-fourth-trials?rq=1) and that the answer and method is the same.  The fact that if we had *not* yet flipped two consecutive heads is irrelevant since the probability that we *eventually* flip two consecutive heads is $1$.  The probability of arriving at the desired outcomes on turn 3 and 4 are exactly the same whether we stop early or not.

Comment: Is that taking into consideration that you could have HH or THH?

Answer (score 0):

Pictured below is a tree diagram of the scenario.  We picture leaves on the tree diagram according to where we either win (have head-head on turn three-four) or know that a loss has already or will inevitably occur (head-head on earlier turns or length of sequence will run too long).

[image: Two heads tree diagram]

The probability of arriving at a specific leaf is the product of the probabilities of traveling along each specific branch.  Considering a fair coin, each branch will be traveled with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

As a result, the probability of success is $(\frac{1}{2})^4+(\frac{1}{2})^4=\frac{2}{16}=\frac{1}{8}$

Alternatively, notice that success or failure is completely determined by the result of the first four coin-flips.  Two of the sixteen possible ways of flipping four coins will result in a win, while the remaining fourteen result in either a preemptive loss or an inevitable loss.

Answer (score 0):

You want the probability that the first four tosses will be $\rm HTH\underline H$ or $\rm TTH\underline H$.   Those are the only outcomes by which the target is met *on* the fouth toss.

If it is $\rm H\underline HTT, H\underline HTH, H\underline HHT, H\underline HHH, TH\underline HT, TH\underline HH$ you will have met the target before the fourth toss; on the second or third, as indicated.

If it is $\rm TTTT, TTTH, TTHT, THTT, THTH, HTTT, HTHT, HTTH$ then you will not meet the target until somewhen after the fourth toss.   You will *certainly* eventually met the target, so the exact number of tries required is not important.

Hence the probability of meeting the target on the fourth toss is: $2/16$