# If a fair coin is tossed until heads appears twice in a row...

Tags: probability

**If a fair coin is tossed until heads appears twice in a row, what is the probability that this coin will be tossed exactly four times?**

I'm trying to teach myself probability and this question came up in the textbook I downloaded [(PDF pg. 38, question 3)](http://bayanbox.ir/view/7776870545953264619/introduction-to-probability-model-S.Ross-math-cs.blog.ir.pdf).  The solutions manual says the answer is **1/8**, because there are two game scenarios (HTHH, TTHH) that will win after four tosses, and there are 16 possible outcomes from flipping a coin 4 times.  1/8 = 2/16, I get that.

My confusion comes from the use of 16 possible outcomes.  Although the book says otherwise, I'm under the impression that the sample space doesn't contain variations such as HHHH and HHTT, since the game would end after HH is tossed.

Is it true that there's only 12 outcomes, so the probability is 2/12, aka 1/6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability of success on third and fourth trials?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617259/probability-of-success-on-third-and-fourth-trials)

Comment: See also the clarification to the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1618969/179297  This appeared on the questions list not even an hour ago.  Please try searching for the question before asking a duplicate.

Comment: I think the key thing to take away here is that the probability of an event isn't always (# of successes)/(size of sample space). Here, the sample space is technically infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The longer enumeration of the sample space is as follows:

$$HH\\
HTHH\\
HTTH\\
HTHT\\
HTTT\\
THH\\
THTH\\
THTT\\
TTHH\\
TTHT\\
TTTH\\
TTTT$$

Ten possible results after up to four tosses. The key is that these ten aren't equally likely.

You get $HH$ one in four times.

You get $THH$ one in eight times.

The rest occur one in 16 times.

This is as if you kept tossing even after the game ended before four tosses. You are still marking the first occurrence of $HH$, you just keep tossing.

Comment: Perfect explanation.  HHTT and HHHH are not in the sample space, as they belong to HH, but my assumption that HH and TTHH have the same probability was invalid.  I understand why it's still 2/16...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Generating Function Approach**

The generating function for the number of possible strings of length $n$ ending in $HH$ is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\overbrace{\left(x+x^2\right)^k}^{\text{$T$ or $HT$}}\overbrace{\quad\ \ x^2\ \ \quad\vphantom{\left(x^2\right)^k}}^{\text{final $HH$}}=\frac{x^2}{1-x-x^2}
$$
The generating function for the [Fibonacci Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is
$$
\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}
$$
Thus, the number of ways to end at $n$ flips is $F_{n-1}$, so the probability of ending at $n$ flips is
$$
\frac{F_{n-1}}{2^n}
$$
Therefore, the probability of ending at $4$ flips is
$$
\frac{F_3}{2^4}=\frac18
$$

---

**Counting (since the number of outcomes is small)**

To count the number of possible outcomes of $4$ flips which end in $HH$ but have no prior double $H$, note that the second flip must be $T$ and that allows the first flip to be $H$ or $T$. Thus, there are $2$ outcomes out of $2^4=16$ that allow us to stop at $4$ flips; that is, $HTHH$ and $TTHH$.

That gives a probability of
$$
\frac2{16}=\frac18
$$

Answer (score 0):

The 16 *equally likely* possibilities are:

- $\rm HH\color{grey}{TT}, HH\color{grey}{TH}, HH\color{grey}{HT}, HH\color{grey}{HH}$ : game actually ends on the second toss. $4/16$
- $\rm THH\color{grey}{T}, THH\color{grey}{H}$ : game ends on the third toss. $2/16$
- $\rm TTHH, HTHH$ : game ends on the fourth toss. $2/16$
- $\rm TTTT, TTTH, TTHT, THTT, THTH, HTTT, HTTH, HTHT$ : game must continue. $8/16$

Although the game actually ends earlier for some results, we can still consider the hypothetical results of additional tosses for the purpose of assigning probability.

And likewise, although the game might require more than four tosses before the target is met, the probability of this happening is the probability that the target is not met on the first four tosses ... ie: $8/16$

Comment: You answered in the linked question just half an hour ago with an almost identical answer.  Why did you not copy/paste or vote to close?